# What are the quadratic residues of an odd prime?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

I need to prove that -1 is a quadratic residue of an odd prime *p* iff *p* = 1 (mod 4)

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: The ammount of times this question's been asked in this site rapidly tends to infinity. Anyway, what have **you** tried so far?

Comment: Not much to be honest. I have a feeling that i will have to use a consequence from eulers criterion and possibly Wilsons Theorem.

Comment: If you are allowed to use Euler's Criterion, then it is one line since $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}=1$ if $p$ is of the form $4k+1$, and is $-1$  otherwise.

Comment: How come? I cant see it?

Answer (score 0):

If $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then we have $-1\equiv a^2\pmod p$, hence
$$
(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv (a^2)^{\frac{p-1}2}=a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p
$$
Hence $p\equiv1\pmod4$ . Now if $p\equiv1\pmod4$, then
$$
-1\equiv \left((\frac{p-1}2)!\right)^2
$$
by Wilson's theorem.